# "run the opposite direction" or "run in the opposite direction"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Tell me please which one of the following srntences is correct.

> The player grabbed the ball and ran the opposite direction.
>
> The player grabbed the ball and ran **in** the opposite direction.

I have heard a native say a similar thing without the preposition. Was it is a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

No.2 is certainly better than No.1

You could say `ran the opposite way` with very similar meaning, so maybe this wasn't really how the words were meant to come out?